# Angular: where to securely add admin features?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I've an **Angular 7 app** and would like to add some **admin** features, like **editing the user's datasets** for them.

I usually prefer to **separate the admin panel** in it's own project, hosted on another Domain to make it a bit harder for potential hackers. Due to the **complexity**, I'd like to **avoid redundancy** this time.

I've no idea if it's supported, but I could think about something like an admin module which is only included during the building process, if a certain flag is set. The result would be **two apps, one codebase**.

Is there any best practice?

Thanks in advance!
*This question should not be opinion-based.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making two separate projects does not improve security. You should not have any admin specific logic in client app. That operation should be handled by backend. So you can deploy same client with admin functionality and manage user privilege in back-end.

```
domain.com  --> client app

domain.com/admin --> server app
```

Comment: Exactly, that's what I prefer. I even host them on separate Domains. I'd just like to avoid the huge amount of redundancy. A solution could be 2 apps on 1 codebase. The client gets everything except the admin module.